# A very strange problem with Overfull \hbox

Tags: sectioning, chapters, warnings

The last two days I face a very strange `Overfull \hbox` problem.

I am writing a book and I am in the 4th chapter. I began writing a 5th chapter, but then I decided to include this in the previous chapter, i.e. chapter 4. And here is the problem. When I write instead of `\chapter{Blah}`,  for 5th chapter, the command `\section{Blah}` (in order to include this in chapter 4), I take the warning `Overfull \hbox (0.91098pt too wide) detected at line 26` ! The same thing happens also when I use chapter 5, *with* subsections. This is very strange. I searched the whole TSE but nothing could solve this problem.

Any help please?

Have a look at the following screenshots. I don't post minimal code because it's very possible this warning be fixed.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Chris (1) We can not reproduce the warning, so it is difficult to help you in an accurate way. You should try to make an MWE. (2) Personally I think you can ignore the warning. Although it is a bit annoying, it's only 0.9pt of text exceeding the margin, i.e. with the naked eye we can't even notice it.

Comment: It seems to happen when the page number has three digits. Probably the place for page numbers in the toc should be enlarged. (Testing if this the problem is easy: simply set tge page number to 100 at the begin)

Comment: @JouleV Thank you for your comment. Ok, I ll try to make an MWE, if the log file does not help.

Comment: @Ulrike Thank you for your comment. I am not sure if the problem is this, because after 100 sometimes works fine (when I use chapter instead of section) and I set 100 to the begin, but nothing changed.

Comment: I don't know how to make a MWE, when I delete some contect to make my code minimal the warning is fixed :(

Comment: chapter toc lines are differently set than section lines (not dots) and so wouldn't give the a warning. And setting to 100 should not avoid the warning but trigger it - that is a *test*.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. So what would you suggest now? Thank you for your time